# d3.js import csv using accessor function and callback

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to understand how to use d3.csv(url[, accessor][, callback])  using both the accessor and the callback function as specified in the official API documentation (see link for point 1). DISCLAIMER: I'm new to d3.js.

**TL,WR: I get an empty console response to the console.log(data) command in the callback function and get undefined when I call console.log on the variable that should be holding the data.**

I have found two easy examples to get to understand how it works.

1. The API itself has an example: [d3.js API at github.com](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV/eb6c4bf82a51c857b003cf07a83456c670a360e1#wiki-parse)
2. A simple example at tonygarcia.me: [Chart-data at tonygarcia.me](http://tonygarcia.me/slides/d3chartintro/#chart-data)

To execute these I have created both an html file for the code and a csv file with the data and then launched a simple server with the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`.

**Case 1: Official API documentation.**

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var datas;
      d3.csv("example.csv", function(d) {
        return {
          year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
          make: d.Make,
          model: d.Model,
          length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number
        };
      }, function(error, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        datas = rows;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The csv (example.csv):

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

The output on the console (empty) and then:

```
> console.log(datas);
undefined                                                        VM2228:2
undefined
```

The expected result:

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": 2.34},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": 2.38}
]
```

**Case 2: Chart-data at tonygarcia.me**

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var datas;
      // load data from a CSV file
      d3.csv('home.csv',
        function(d) {
          return {
            key: d.state,
            value: +d.value
          };
        }, function(dataset){
          // code to generate chart goes here
          datas = dataset;
          console.log( dataset );
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The cvs (home.cvs):

```
state,value
Alabama,71.6
Alaska,22.4
Arizona,147.5
Arkansas,59.9
<truncated>
```

The output on the console (empty) and then:

```
> console.log(datas);
undefined                                                         VM2265:2
undefined
```

The expected result (you can try it on the webpage):

```
[{"key":"Alabama","value":71.6},{"key":"Alaska","value":22.4},     
{"key":"Arizona","value":147.5},{"key":"Arkansas","value":59.9},...]
```

So, what am I doing wrong? If I only use a callback function with no accessor everything works. Using the accessor is interesting to format the data from sting to f.e. number.

Thank you all for your help!

Best,

Michael

EDIT: Correction: tonygarcia.com --> tonygarcia.me

Comment: I confirm what you said above. Copied your code and csv, everything is the same as you said.

Comment: I tried loading d3.v3.min.js from Toni Garcia web site to your example and it did not change anything.

Comment: I tried that too and got the same result. That rules out version incompatibilities as we are using the same d3.js code as him. I really don't understand what is going on. Could it be about the python server?

Comment: So I looked further into the server issue and launched a node server. Same behaviour, that wasn't the issue. I then went back to check out d3.js versions. I tried requesting the latest d3.js version to see if it would work. Bingo. Version 3 works. It is still a mystery to me how Toni Garcia pulls it off. Will post answer.

Comment: Congratulations! nmaybe even it doesnt work on garcias site, just nobody notices, including him...

Comment: Thanks VividD! The tonigarcia.me page I link above actually has a "Run" code button that performs the operation correctly (You can try and see the output). Furthermore, I checked his site's code and it seems to be working. Dunno, I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a version issue. v3 works, v2 doesn't.

This code links to v2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">
</script>
```

To be exact it's contents are:

```
document.write("<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js'></script>");
```

To make it work I linked it to the newest version like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
</script>
```

This solves the main issue and I will consider the question solved. (Haven't figured out how Toni Garcia is doing it as I used his js and couldn't get it working, but this is irrelevant.)

Thanks all for your help and sorry for answering my own question.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer today (I'm a noob with no rep) but will do so tomorrow. Thanks again to all!

Answer (score 1):

the callback should be set up like so:

```
d3.csv("your_file_url.csv", function (error, data) {
//Here you should put the code for your visualization.
});
```

Your first example would then be:

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function (error, data) {
console.log(data) // this will output the data contained in your csv
});
```

The fact is that the function d3.csv already parses the data as it gets loaded, so if you load the example.csv file it will be read and then treated like an array of values

Comment: Hey, @tomtomtom, thats fine what you wrote, but he is asking about another flavor of d3.csv, with three arguments, why that doesn't work, and it is documented. That's how I understand him.

Comment: yes but to change the d.value from string to value it could be done easily with dataset.forEach(function (d) { d.value = +d.value; }); I think he asked how to set up the callback correctly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am indeed looking to do what VividD is saying. I agree with you that you can set up a forEach in the callback function to get the same result but why doesn't the accessor function work if it is clearly stated in the API documentation. And even more surprisingly, why does it work flawlessly on the tonygarcia.me webpage.